# How Do I make My GTK# program quit?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#, quit

I started learning GTK#, and I wrote my first GUI program. When I ran it through the terminal, it didn't quit the program when i clicked the X in the top corner. I ran it again while looking at my task manager, and indeed it doesn't quit. I have to manually kill it. Do I need a special code for it to quit?
My current code is

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public class GtkHelloWorld {

  public static void Main() {
    Application.Init();

    //Create the Window
    Window myWin = new Window("My first GTK# Application! ");
    myWin.Resize(200,200);

    //Create a label and put some text in it.     
    Label myLabel = new Label();
    myLabel.Text = "Hello World!!!!";

    //Add the label to the form     
    myWin.Add(myLabel);

    //Show Everything     
    myWin.ShowAll();

    Application.Run();   
  }
}
```

I compiled it against version 4 of mono, so I have to run it in the terminal with `mono --runtime=v4.0 /path/to/file.exe`

Comment: It sounds like you have overwritten the default action, not upto speed on mono + gtk, but you could overwrite it with something such as this.Dispose()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quit, you need to call `Application.Quit ();`. Generally, the way people do this is by connecting to the window's DeleteEvent like this:

```
myWin.DeleteEvent += delegate (sender, args) {
    Application.Quit ();
};
```